# Flexdashboard in R - Columns Orientation

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am trying to design my Dashboard in R through Markdown, but I am not able get exactly the design wished.

[image]

In the section **Tab** I want to insert {.tabset} option keeping the same design above. Nevertheless, when I try do it, the design changed for the image below:

[image]
Could someone help insert the **.tab** format in the first image design?

Below the first R Markdown code

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

`r knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, cache = F)`

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.fluid-row {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
```

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# Libraries ---------------------------------------------------------------
pacman::p_load(ggplot2, tidyr, readxl ,dplyr, forcats, fitdistrplus,lubridate,
               tseries, forecast, timetk, zoo,wktmo, plotly,magrittr,
               widgetframe, data.table, webshot, htmlwidgets,stringr,
               formattable, calendR, flexdashboard)


options(scipen=999)
setwd('/media/arduin/Ubuntu HDD/02. Sanofi/04. Calendar')

```


Page 1
===================================== 

Row {.tabset}
-------------------------------------

### Tab
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='hide'}

```

Row
-------------------------------------
### Tabla 1
```{r, echo=FALSE, error=TRUE, fig.height=8, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

```

Column {.tabset}
-------------------------------------
   
### Graph 1

```{r, attr.output='style="max-height: 100px;"'}

```   
 
### Graph 2
    
```{r}

```

### Graph 3
    
```{r}


```

### Graph 4
```{r}

```


### Graph 5
```{r}


```
````

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image]

````
---
title: "Flexdashboard"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

Page 1
=====================================    
Column {data-width=400}
-------------------------------------
   
### Chart 1

```{r}
```   
 
### Chart 2
    
```{r}
```    
    
Column {.tabset data-width=400}
-------------------------------------
   
### Graph 3

```{r}

```   
 
### Graph 4
    
```{r}

```

### Graph 5
    
```{r}


```

### Graph 6
```{r}

```
````

I used [This link](https://pkgs.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/articles/layouts.html) for the layout code, I think you may want `Column`, not `Row` when making the boxes, also the `data-width` helps with the layout like it shows in the link

Comment: Almost perfect, but I wanna put .tab in the the chart 1. So I would have something like chart1a, chart1b, and chart1c. in the same place.